# No wifi for importing google data in lineageos gapps setup wizard

Tags: google, lineageos

After fresh install of lineageos 14.1 and gapps ROMs, the gapps setup wizard asks whether to perform a fresh setup or to import data from the cloud, e.g. google backup using your google account.  Unfortunately, wifi is not setup yet by the wizard ensuring that any import from the cloud will fail.  Does this mean it's not possible to directly import your data from the cloud during lineageos gapps setup?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: The last sentence is not rhetorical and ends in a question mark.

Answer (score 1):

This is a silly bug, but it can be worked around by starting the fresh installation which will immediately prompt you to setup wifi.  Connect to your wifi then go BACK to the point where the import from cloud option is available and proceed with import of google data / installation of apps.

Comment: Should mark this as solved, at least it solved it for me.